# How can I query XML node (elements and attributes) correctly by grouping multiple attributes using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Here is my xml code:

```
<IW version="2.0"> 
<Quote QuoteId="23206810" PackageId="10" EffectiveDate="9/8/2020">
    <Vehicle VehicleId="41257627" DriverId="116367578" Description="2009 Toyota COROLLA BASE/S/LE/XLE 4-Door Sedan 2T1BU40E19C181192 ">
      <Feature Value="BI" Premium="396">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.55</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="PD" Premium="469">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.55</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="UMBI" Premium="184">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.55</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="UMPD" Premium="78">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.55</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="OTC" Premium="192">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.45</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="COL" Premium="1334">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
          <Value>2.25</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle VehicleId="41257628" DriverId="116367577" Description="2009 Hyundai SANTA FE GLS SPORT UTILITY 4-DR 5NMSG13D79H328179 ">
      <Feature Value="BI" Premium="421">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.65</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="PD" Premium="511">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.65</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="PIP" Premium="403">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.65</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="UMBI" Premium="196">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.65</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="UMPD" Premium="83">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.65</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="OTC" Premium="181">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.3</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="COL" Premium="1064">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
          <Value>2</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle VehicleId="41257625" DriverId="116367575" Description="2006 Nissan ALTIMA S/SE/SL/SE-R 4-Door Sedan 1N4AL11D36C142780 ">
      <Feature Value="BI" Premium="254">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.15</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="PD" Premium="301">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.15</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="PIP" Premium="286">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.15</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="UMBI" Premium="130">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.15</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="UMPD" Premium="50">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.15</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="OTC" Premium="121">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
          <Value>0.9</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Value="COL" Premium="490">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1.05</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>7</Order>
        </Factor>
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>12</Order>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
    </Vehicle>
  </Quote>
</IW>
```

Here is my T-SQL code.  I am not getting any results back.

```
;WITH CTECastToXml as (
    SELECT CAST(qf.FactorXml as xml) as x, nbq.PackageId
    FROM dbo.AUT_QuoteFactors qf
    INNER JOIN #tempNotBoundQuote nbq
    ON qf.QuoteId = nbq.QuoteID
    WHERE qf.QuoteId = 23206810
)
SELECT a.qp.value('@QuoteId','varchar(max)') as QuoteID
    ,a.qp.value('@PackageId','varchar(max)') as PackageId
    ,b.v.value('@VehicleId', 'varchar(max)') as VehicleId
    ,b.v.value('@DriverId', 'varchar(max)') as DriverId
    ,c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') as Coverage
    ,CASE 
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'BI' THEN c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)') 
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'PD' THEN c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)') 
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'PIP' THEN  c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)')
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'UMBI' THEN  c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)')
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'UMPD' THEN  c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)')
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'TL' THEN  c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)')
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'RR' THEN  c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)')
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'OTC' THEN  c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)')
        WHEN c.v.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'COL' THEN  c.v.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)')
        ELSE 0.00
    END as Premium
    ,CASE
        WHEN d.v.value('Relativity[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'Driver Class' THEN e.v.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        ELSE ''
    END as DriverClass
    --,CASE
    --  WHEN d.v.value('Relativity[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'Driver Points' THEN e.v.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    --  ELSE ''
    --END as DriverPoints
FROM CTECastToXml cte
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/IW/Quote') as a(qp)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/IW/Quote/Vehicle') as b(v)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/IW/Quote/Vehicle/Feature') as c(v)
**CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/IW/Quote/Vehicle/Feature/Factor/Relativity') as d(v)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/IW/Quote/Vehicle/Feature/Factor/RelativityKey') as e(v)**
WHERE a.qp.value('@PackageId','varchar(max)') = cte.PackageId
ORDER BY VehicleId asc, DriverId asc;
```

Any help/direction would be great. I am not proficient at XML as I don't work with it everyday but the problem appears to be when I added the bolded lines CROSS APPLY BEFORE THE WHERE CLAUSE ... lines above.  Thanks.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. For your case: 
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DDL and sample data population is not provided, I am guessing that you need something along the following:

**T-SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FactorXml NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (FactorXml) VALUES
(N'<IW version="2.0">
    <Quote QuoteId="23206810" PackageId="10" EffectiveDate="9/8/2020">
        <Vehicle VehicleId="41257627" DriverId="116367578"
                 Description="2009 Toyota COROLLA BASE/S/LE/XLE 4-Door Sedan 2T1BU40E19C181192 ">
            <Feature Value="BI" Premium="396">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.55</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="PD" Premium="469">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.55</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="UMBI" Premium="184">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.55</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="UMPD" Premium="78">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.55</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="OTC" Premium="192">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.45</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="COL" Premium="1334">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>MS21</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>2.25</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
        </Vehicle>
        <Vehicle VehicleId="41257628" DriverId="116367577"
                 Description="2009 Hyundai SANTA FE GLS SPORT UTILITY 4-DR 5NMSG13D79H328179 ">
            <Feature Value="BI" Premium="421">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.65</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="PD" Premium="511">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.65</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="PIP" Premium="403">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.65</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="UMBI" Premium="196">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.65</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="UMPD" Premium="83">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.65</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="OTC" Premium="181">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.3</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="COL" Premium="1064">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FS19</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>2</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
        </Vehicle>
        <Vehicle VehicleId="41257625" DriverId="116367575"
                 Description="2006 Nissan ALTIMA S/SE/SL/SE-R 4-Door Sedan 1N4AL11D36C142780 ">
            <Feature Value="BI" Premium="254">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.15</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="PD" Premium="301">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.15</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="PIP" Premium="286">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.15</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="UMBI" Premium="130">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.15</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="UMPD" Premium="50">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.15</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="OTC" Premium="121">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>0.9</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Value="COL" Premium="490">
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Class</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>FM45</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1.05</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                </Factor>
                <Factor>
                    <Relativity>Driver Points</Relativity>
                    <RelativityKey>0</RelativityKey>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Rounding>3</Rounding>
                    <Order>12</Order>
                </Factor>
            </Feature>
        </Vehicle>
    </Quote>
</IW>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT TRY_CAST(FactorXml AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT c.value('@QuoteId','INT') as QuoteID
    , c.value('@PackageId','INT') as PackageId
    , v.value('@VehicleId', 'INT') as VehicleId
    , v.value('@DriverId', 'INT') as DriverId
    , f.value('@Value', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Coverage
    , CASE 
        WHEN f.value('@Value', 'varchar(20)') IN ('BI','PD','PIP','UMBI','UMPD', 'TL', 'RR', 'OTC', 'COL') THEN f.value('@Premium', 'decimal(8,2)') 
        ELSE 0.00
    END as Premium
    , CASE
        WHEN fa.value('(Relativity/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') = 'Driver Class' 
            THEN fa.value('(RelativityKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
        ELSE ''
    END as DriverClass
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/IW/Quote') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('Vehicle') AS b(v)
    CROSS APPLY b.v.nodes('Feature') AS t3(f)
    CROSS APPLY t3.f.nodes('Factor') AS d(fa);
```

Comment: Yitzhak, thank you for your response.  I'm trying to understand what you did.  My apologies for not providing the DDL table data but now I know how.  The problem that I now have is trying to roll-up the data output as I now have duplicate rows with different data elements.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Melinda, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please connect with me on LinkedIn. In regards to roll-ups, you can add one more CTE, or just a `GROUP BY` right away.

Comment: Yes.  Got the rollup issue resolved.  TY again.  I would like to ask you some questions on this later on if you don't mind after reviewing what you did in the code.

Comment: @Melinda, Sure. We can have an interactive session where you can ask me any question.